# ckeditor4 editorConfig and editorUrl is not working in react?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

i have download full package of ckeditorckeditor_4.14.1_full.zip and extract in my assets folder but when i use this dir as `CKEditor.editorUrl = '../assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';` then it's not working, if i use CDN like `CKEditor.editorUrl = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/full/ckeditor.js';`  then it's working fine and editorConfig is not working also...
would you like to tell me how can i define that?

createForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';

CKEditor.editorUrl = '../assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'; // this link is not working...

//CKEditor.editorUrl = '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/full/ckeditor.js'; it's working!

CKEditor.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.uiColor = '#2b2c26';
    config.contentsCss = '../assets/desk/fonts/Nafees-Nastaleeq/css/font.css';
    config.font_names = 'Nafees Nastaleeq;' + config.font_names;
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h2>Using CKEditor 4 in React</h2>
                <CKEditor
                    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 CKEditor.editorUrl = '../assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
```

should be

```js
CKEditor.editorUrl = '/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
```

if it is not work you could and your site url by using process.env

```js
import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react'
CKEditor.editorUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`
```

you could set **REACT_APP_BASE_URL** for prod and development

Answer (score 0):

Try to expose the ckeditor.js file from your server, and use the http url as

CKEditor.editorUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/ckeditor/ckeditor.js';